# NodeJS, multiple access on the same varible

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to build rooms and groups with websockets (I know there is socket.io, but I have to use native websockets)

I'm wondering how I safely can update my groups array: It looks like this:

```
let socketStore = {10:[ws1, ws2], 20:[ws3, ws3]}
```

10 and 20 are group ids and the websockets are stored inside the arrays.

Imagine this code for a socket closing his connection:

```
ws.on("close", ()=>{
        let userId = ws.userId;
        try{
            Object.keys(socketStore).forEach((groupId)=>{
                if(socketStore[groupId].length === 1){
                    //what if after that a user joined again?
                    delete socketStore[groupId];
                    console.log("delete group key")
                }else{
                    let index = socketStore[groupId].findIndex(ws => ws.userId ===userId)
                    if(index != -1){
                        socketStore[groupId].splice(index, 1)
                        console.log("delete user socket")
                    }
                }
            })
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
```

So I iterate through all group ids and check if the user is a member of this group. Moreover I check if there is only one member left, so i can delete the group key. But if the after that `if(socketStore[groupId].length === 1)` another socket connects and is added to the array? But then the array would be still deleted although there are now two users inside. Or is is the object `socketStore` inside this if-condition just a copy of the global one?

Can I be sure that inside that if-condition, `socketStore` hasn't changed?

I don't know how NodeJS is handling this kind of multiple access on the same variable.

In addition, what about different promises/callbacks updating the `socketStore`. Do they update the original one, or do they get a copy at the beginning?
Can you help me?

Comment: Node.js is single-threaded. Other code only runs when you explicitly let it. Your entire handler is synchronous, so it runs as one uninterrupted block.

Comment: so there I can be sure, that in the if-condition, the socketStore object isn't changed? What about asynchronous tasks ?